# how to filter by age in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filter

I need to add a filter to filter data by a persons age.
Below is the code i am using for to filter tel and phone numbers.

The feild that collects/holds my customers DOB is "app.DOB"

Please assist me

```
Friend Overrides Function Filter() As String

            Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

            If (Not app.LandPhone.StartsWith("01")) And (Not app.LandPhone.StartsWith("02")) Then
                sb.Append("Land phone must be present and start 01 or 02;")
            End If

            If (Not app.WorkPhone.StartsWith("01")) And (Not app.WorkPhone.StartsWith("02")) And (Not app.WorkPhone.StartsWith("08")) Then
                sb.Append("Work phone must be present and start 01, 02 or 08;")
            End If

            If app.MobilePhone = String.Empty Then
                sb.Append("Mobile phone must be present;")
            End If


            Return sb.ToString()
        End Function
```

Comment: Is app.DOB a String, Integer, Datetime. Who do you want to filter out/in ... We need more information. And also what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry it is a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DOb is of datetime, then the `DateDiff` function will be usefull.it will be like

```
if DateDiff(DateInterval.day,app.DOB,Date.Today)/365 > your filter value
''what you want to do
end if
```

**Note:**
now only i noticed your comment that it is string.i that case convert it to date using parseexact before using in datediff function like

if format of you DOB column is dd/MM/yyyy then

```
 Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact(app.DOB, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
if DateDiff(DateInterval.day,dt,Date.Today)/365 > your filter value
'' what you want
end if
```

you can change the format according to your grid format:

Comment: No i cant change the format according to  grid format , i need to filter it between ages 30 - 70 years

Comment: what is the date format in column DOB.is it dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Note that you can't use `DateDiff` with `DateInterval.Year` to get the age of someone.